# linq to entity save

Tags: linq-to-entities, repository, relation

I have a following database structure.

[image]

I have already saved `Buyer` in database. I have `buyer id`. I have to save contact information of a buyer in the database, as I save contact in the database I also need to save `buyercontact` in `buyercontact` table. When I try to add `BuyerContact` table in the edmx file, Visual Studio 2010 won't allow me to do that.

How do I save information in `buyercontact` table? Please help.

They say if appropriate relationship is maintained in the database/edmx, buyercontact will be saved to database as well when i cave "contact". I search through the internet, i also found similar questions asked but i could not understand.

Please help. do i have to write some special code to save `BuyerContact`

When I write this code to save contact along with `buyercontact`,  I get error

> Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   dbo.Buyer

```
Contact objContact = new Contact();
objContact.FirstName = firstName;
objContact.MiddleName = middleName;
objContact.Lastname = lastName;
objContact.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
objContact.AddressId = gAddressId;                    

var buyer = _buyerRepository.GetSingle(x => x.BuyerId == BuyerID);
objContact.Buyer = buyer;

_contactRepository.Add(objContact);
_contactRepository.Save()
```

If I remove `objContact.Buyer = buyer;`, then contact information is saved successfully but `buyercontact` is not saved. Now my problem is as soon as I have contact associated with the buyer I also need to save it in the `BuyerContact` table.

I have already been through post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025823/save-a-relation-with-between-two-entities-an-n-n-association), but O could not understand. I have used generic Linq-to-SQL repository for common database operations like CRUD.

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this, instead of:

```
objContact.Buyer = buyer;
_contactRepository.Add(objContact);
_contactRepository.Save()
```

replace with:

```
buyer.Contacts.Add(objContact);
_buyerRepository.Save();
```

also assuming you are using same context object across all repositories for unit of work